# "Concept of Universe" vs "concept of the Universe", what is the difference?

Tags: difference, articles

I met both variants and I feel that there is an important difference between them? But I cannot pinpoint it

Comment: It would help to have more context.  Can you show us where you found these sentences?

Comment: I have discovered that the same book  by Walter Russell is referred to both as "A New Concept of  Universe", and as "A New Concept of the Universe", by Walter Russell  https://www.google.ru/search?q=%22Concept%2Bof%2BUniverse%22+Russel%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=kK3yVs2uBuagyAPniYPgAQ

Comment: In that sense, the first title means a new idea of what a universe is, whereas the second means a new idea of the universe we live in. The same definitions apply that I mention in my answer below.

Comment: Based on English language links I've seen for this book and the description of the book itself, I'd say "A New Concept of the Universe" is the correct title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concept):

> 1 : something conceived in the mind :  thought, notion
>
> 2 : an abstract or generic idea generalized from particular instances

"Concept of the universe" uses the first definition and "concept of universe" uses the second.

Here are a couple of example usages:

> In my astrophysics class, we studied the concept of universe.

In other words, we studied the abstract idea "universe".

> When I realized how small I was, I had a better concept of the universe.

In other words, I had a better thought or notion of what the universe was.

Answer (score 0):

> Concept of Universe

The Universe itself is a concept.

> Concept of the Universe

The Universe has a concept about something.